# TypeInitializationException trown while importing Video with EmguCV

Tags: c#, video, exception, emgucv

I am working on a Project where I want an User to be able to import a Video. Every time, when I choose the video I want to import, `public class CvString : UnmanagedObject` is throwing me a `System.TypeInitializationException` Error. This does not depend on the Data Type, it doesn't work for pics, like `.jpeg` or `.png`, nor does it work for any videoformat I have tried (``` .avi``.mp4``.wmp ```)

This is the snippet where I want to load and display the video (own written code)

```
OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
Capture _capture;
Timer My_Time = new Timer();
int FPS = 30;
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    //Frame Rate
    My_Time.Interval = 1000 / FPS;
    My_Time.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
    My_Time.Start();

    _capture = new Capture("20151102_110553.mp4");

}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    imageBox1.Image = _capture.QueryFrame();
}


private void openFileDialog1_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    _capture = new Capture(openFileDialog1.FileName.ToString());
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//Import-Button
{
     openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
}
```

And here is the Method where the Exception is thrown (code from Emgu.CV)

```
namespace Emgu.CV
{
   public class CvString : UnmanagedObject
   { 
        private bool _needDispose;

        internal CvString(IntPtr ptr, bool needDispose)
        {
             _ptr = ptr;
             _needDispose = needDispose;
        }

        public CvString(String s)
        {
        if (s == null)
            {
                _ptr = CvInvoke.cveStringCreate();
            }
        else
        {
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s);
            Array.Resize(ref bytes, bytes.Length + 1);
            bytes[bytes.Length - 1] = 0; //The end of string '\0' character
            GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(bytes, GCHandleType.Pinned);
            _ptr =CvInvoke.cveStringCreateFromStr(handle.AddrOfPinnedObject());
            // ^ Exception is thrown ^
            handle.Free();
        }

        _needDispose = true;
    }
```

I have already tried importing the videos or pictures into my project, importing it directly while starting the project, or by using an `OpenFileDialog` to choose the file while running, but with the same results. As soon as I choose a file and want to load it into my project, the Exception is thrown.

**EDIT : Stack Trace added**

Stack Trace

```
No suitable directory found to load unmanaged modules
Exception thrown : "System.DllNotFoundException" in Emgu.CV.dll
Exception thrown : "System.TypeInitializationException" in Emgu.CV.dll
Thread 0xa64 ended with Code 0 (0x0).
Exception thrown : "System.TypeInitializationException" in Emgu.CV.dll
Exception thrown : "System.TypeInitializationException" in Emgu.CV.dll
Exception thrown : "System.TypeInitializationException" in Emgu.CV.dll
```

Comment: Are there any static variables in the . . . Part of that class? Can you add the stack trace please?

Comment: I have added the code from the `...` part. What do you mean by stack trace?

Comment: When you catch an Exception, or when the debugger catches an exception, check the StackTrace property in the exception details. The StackTrace is a string, you can copy and paste it here

Comment: the whole one was too large, I took the part where the exception was thrown.

Comment: This is not the stack trace, but at least, has the message. I think it is looking for Assets\Plugins folder and cannot find it. You can use Process Monitor from sys internals to see what directory it is looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had the same Problem once, and I don't know if it helps you, but try it out.

Just drag and Drop the `cvextern`, `msvcp120`, `msvcr120` and `opencv_ffmpeg300_64` dll in your project. They should be located in `emgu...\bin\x64\`.

This should fix your `DllNotFoundException`, and maybe the rest.